# Less: Ignore a rule when in development mode

Tags: css, less

Is there a way in less to ignore a css rule when in development mode, but then show that rule after less has compiled.

for instance in a file foo.less

```
.foo {
  background: green; //ignore this file in development mode
}
```

but the corresponding css file would use this rule

Comment: Not exactly sure what you mean. Is there a way to use less without compiling? Maybe 'development mode' is particular to your IDE?

Comment: Well I'm using grunt to build all the less files into one css file.  What i mean by development mode is I'm using less.js which applies the css rules.  Then production mode uses the compiled css file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just adding a variable in the less files and then overwriting that variable with less.js while in dev mode:

```
less.modifyVars({ foo: "auto" })
```

then in the less file:

```
@foo: green
.foo {
   background: @foo
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you use different environments for production and development anyway it would be easier to simply wrap you less code with another less file for "debug" mode only, e.g.:

```
// ---------
// main.less - this is your main less built with grunt

// ...
// all your code here
// ...

@debug: false;

.foo {
    & when not(@debug) {background: green} // ignore this file in development mode
}

// ----------
// debug.less - this is the "development" wrapper to use with less.js in a browser

@import "main.less"
@debug: true;
```

## -

`& when` shortcut requires LESS 1.5.1, for earlier versions use:

```
.-() when not(@debug) {
    background: green;
} .-;
```

instead.